# How to format a number stored as text in a cell as a number after import or copy/paste | Excel | VBA | Solution

Tags: excel, vba, import, number-formatting

First off, thank you to everyone on here, the posts have helped me come far.

This has broken my head and taken days to solve. Posting it here in the hopes that it helps.

**Problem Statement**

I have to copy or import an exported CSV or Excel document into a working excel document on a weekly basis. When I do this, all the numbers are stored as text, with the little green icon and the error symbol that alerts you that a number is potentially stored as text.

It is impossible to fix this. You can highlight the cell or the column and set the number formatting to number, but until you double click each cell, it still won't change the type. I tried to automate this with VBA to no avail. No matter what "hack" I try to cast or change number formatting nothing "logical" worked.

(I have some coding experience in C++, but VBA seems to be an entirely different beast! :) )

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Trying to fix this with VBA proved impossible by just changing the cell number format type. I tried many things until I stumbled on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240449/convert-number-stored-as-text-to-number), solution number two.

The key is to assign the cell value to itself after setting the formatting.

The below subroutine iterates through a sheet and depending on if a known string matches it fixes the number formatting for the number in the adjacent cell.  (This is the problem statement I saw most other noobies struggle with so leaving it here in the hopes that it helps anyone new get started.)

```
Sub SelectiveFixRowFormat()
 
Dim longI As Long 'iterator for each row
Dim longLastRow As Long  'max used row in the sheet
Dim strSearchString As String 'String I am searching for that will have to have the number in the column next to it formatted correctly
 
strSearchString = "QuickBrownFox "
 
'find the last row with something in it.
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
'main For-loop to loop through each cell.
For longI = 1 To lRow
    If Cells(longI, "C") = strSearchString Then 'only if the text matches the offending entry, change formatting
        Cells(longI, "E").NumberFormat = "0" ' This step does nothing to change the appearance. This is where I see most noobs like me stop completely perplexed.
        Cells(longI, "E").Value = Cells(longI, "E").Value ' This step, which seems absolutely meaningless is what actually gets excel to update the cell's formatting from text to number, fix the appearance, and makes all my vlookups work.
        
    End If
       
Next longI
   
End Sub
```

To restate it simpler, if you need to automate the formatting of numbers after a copy/paste or import routine, it's a two-step process. you have to assign the cell number format and them assign the cell value to itself to "trigger" the change.

```
Cells(X,Y).NumberFormat = "0" 'Set Formatting, doesnt "do" anything
Cells(X,Y).Value = Cells(X,Y).Value 'fixes the display and cell value type so that functions can work on numbers.
```

This seems embarrassingly simple nut I searched long and hard and could not find the solution clearly explained anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find a blank cell on the worksheet on which you have your text values and enter the number 1.
2. Select this cell and press Copy (or Ctl+C)
3. Select the range containing numbers in text format.
4. From the ribbon's Home tab, Click Paste > Paste Special. Check *Multiply* and press OK.

All text values will be converted to numbers (multiplied with 1). Real text stays unaffected. Of course, the same idea can also be executed using VBA.